# OuterDiv box shadow always be on top

Tags: html, css

I have my main-container div having box shadow. There will be a inner div which will contain a list. I want box shadow always be on top of inner container so if list goes out of div it get hidden behind shadow.

Here is code:

```
<div class="main-container bg-logged-in">

<div class="data scrollbar" id="agenda-data">
</div>


</div>

.bg-logged-in {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #3f3f3f;
    box-shadow: 0 -2.2em #25a0da inset, 0 -2.7em #3f3f3f inset, 0 -3em #25a0da inset;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

}

.content-left .data {
    bottom: 1em;
    height: 65%;
    top: 6.5em;
    width: 100%;
}
.scrollbar {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: please show your attempts, provide a fiddle

Comment: did you try overflow: hidden property?

Comment: from your sample, it's still unclear what you're trying to achieve and what it should look like. Also, your box-shadow definition seems incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this:

```
.bg-logged-in {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #3f3f3f;
left: 0;
right: 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: 8px 6px 13px 0px #25a0da;
-moz-box-shadow:    8px 6px 13px 0px #25a0da;
box-shadow:         8px 6px 13px 0px #25a0da;
}
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/anikcse/03oss6ae/)

You Can generate your box shadow using [this](http://css3gen.com/box-shadow/) site.